# In ASP.NET MVC Core, what do the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design packages do?

Tags: asp.net-core

Are they only needed at design time? Can they be removed without causing any build issues? (Targeting framework netcoreapp2.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` [**contains MSBuild support for Razor**](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.csproj#L3). If you're developing an asp.net core app, **there's no need to add an package reference on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` manually (and also you're not supposed to remove them manually)**. Because **it is referenced by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package, which means if you have a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, you'll reference the package automatically**.

The package of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` is a quite different one. **As the name suggests, it is used to generate codes only**. For example, you want to develop a project **without `Visual Studio`**:

1. You create a new project using the command of **`dotnet new mvc`**
2. And then you create a new Model named `App.Models.MyModel` mannually
3. Typically, we'll use `Visual Studio` to generate controllers, views, DbContext and so on. But what if we don't have `Visual Studio`?

**If we have the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` referenced in our `*.csproj` file, we can create the CRUD scaffold using the following command** :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -m $model -dc $dcClass -name $controllerName -namespace $controllerNamespace -outDir Controllers --useDefaultLayout
```

There're also some other sub commands such as :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc $dcClass
```

However, this package is only used to scaffold. Once you have the codes generated, you can feel free to remove this package before publish.

As a side note, to use the `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` command, we should first install the tool:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 3.x (running on .NET Core 3.x), the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package is referenced implicitly and should not have an explicit PackageReference in the project. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design is no longer produced and its reference should be removed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Palec You're describing *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design* while I'm using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` ? This package is used automatically by VS even in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: I was referring to the first paragraph of your answer. The rest talks about Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design, but the first paragraph talks about the packages I mentioned.

Comment: @Palec Oh I see. This answer was written a years ago.  Thanks for your feedback. I didn't notice that :)